# Does $\mathrm{Inn}(G) = \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ imply $Z(G) = \{e\}$? Can $|G| > |\mathrm{Aut}(G)|$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is there a group $G$ whose conjugation map<sup>1</sup> $G \to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is surjective without being injective?

More generally, is there a group $G$ (not necessarily finite) such that $|G| > |\mathrm{Aut}(G)|$?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> I.e. the map sending every $g\in G$ to the automorphism of $G$ defined by $x\mapsto g\,x\,g^{-1}$.</sub>

Comment: for the second question (which is actually not more general than the first, I think) let $G = \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{{p}}$.

Comment: I wrote "more generally" for the second statement because I was thinking of it as one about *all* maps $G \to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$, in contrast to the first one, which is a statement *one specific* map $G \to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$.

Comment: oh I see! i think the rest of the answer is right.

Comment: I am glad you asked this question.  It will be good to link to for future questions predicated upon these common errors.

Answer (score 4):

For your second question, take $G=\mathbb{Z}$. Then $Aut(G) \cong C_2$. For a finite case take $G = C_p$, a cyclic group of prime order $p$. Then $Aut(G) \cong C_{p-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

For the first question, here are the smallest three examples:

- $G=C_2$
- $G=C_2 \times \operatorname{A\Gamma L}(1,8)$
- $G\cong 2\cdot 2^3 \cdot 2^3 : 7$ is the normalizer of a Sylow 2-subgroup in a double cover of Suzuki's simple group of order 29120

The second one generalizes to $C_2 \times \operatorname{A\Gamma L}(1,2^{2n+1})$. The latter direct factor is a complete group with no normal subgroups of index 2. Derek Holt mentions $C_2 \times M_{11}$ as another such group.

The first and third ones are neat because they are directly indecomposable.

**I am interested in more indecomposable examples.**

I know there are no such examples that are $p$-groups other than $C_2$. I find it odd that $2\cdot 2^3 \cdot 2^3 : 7$ exists, but $2 \cdot 2^3 : 7$ does not. Is there a $2 \cdot 2^3 \cdot 2^3 \cdot 2^3 : 7$?

Comment: The Sylow 2-normalizer $2^2\cdot 2^3\cdot 2^3 :7:3$ in the fully decorated $2^2\cdot \operatorname{Sz}(8):3$ is also an indecomposable such group.

Comment: I was wondering whether there were indecomposable examples in which $Z(G)$ is arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 3):

For the first question, you could take $G = S \times C_2$, where $S$ is a nonabelian simple group with trivial outer automorphism group. For example, $S=M_{11}$.

Answer (score 3):

Nice to know (more than the OP asked for but strongly related): in group theory a group $G$ is called *complete* if both $Aut(G)=Inn(G)$ and $Z(G)=1$. An example is $G=S_3$.

**Theorem** If a $N$ is a normal complete subgroup of a group $G$, then it is a direct factor of $G$.
**Proof** (sketch) In general for $N \unlhd G$, there is a homomorphism $G/NC_G(N) \hookrightarrow Out(N):=Aut(N)/Inn(N)$, so $G=NC_G(N)$. And $N \cap C_G(N)=Z(N)=1$, whence $G=N \times C_G(N)$.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of this map is the center of $G$, so you demand that $G$ have a non-trivial center and no outer automorphisms.

I think that $G = S_3 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ does the job. Clearly it has a center (the second factor). Any automorphism fixes the center so induces an automorphism of $S_3$ which is inner.

EDIT: above is wrong (see comments). I am starting to believe the answer could be negative. For a $p$-group it is never true.

EDIT 2: well, now that I think about it, $G = \mathbb{Z}/2$ answers OP's original question, although not in a very satisfying way.

Comment: Your example is not correct. The group $G = S_3 \times C_2$ has $12$ automorphisms, and $G / Z(G) \cong \operatorname{Inn}(G)$ has order $6$.

Comment: ah rats -- where are the outer automorphisms coming from?

Comment: (the problem with my argument is that if $\phi$ is an automorphism, then $\phi$ must fix the center but it doesn't follow that $\phi(\sigma, 1)$ is of the form $(\tau, 1)$.)

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen: $|\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/2)| = 1$, not $2$.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @kjo no, he is right -- indeed $S_3 \times C_2 = D_6$ and the automorphism group has order 12. The problem is that there are automorphisms intertwining the two factors.

Comment: @hunter: it'd be interesting to see an automorphism that is not of the form $(\sigma, 0)$

Comment: @kjo: You are correct that $\mathbb{Z}/2$ has exactly one automorphism. But note that if $H$ and $K$ do not have coprime order, the formula $\operatorname{Aut}(H \times K) \cong \operatorname{Aut}(H) \times \operatorname{Aut}(K)$ might not hold.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen: sorry, I misinterpreted your argument...

Comment: @kjo: Let $\alpha$ be the central element in the $C_2$ factor. There are $6$ outer automorphisms: they are the ones that map $(12)$ from the $S_3$ factor to $(12)\alpha$, $(13)\alpha$ or $(23)\alpha$. Inner automorphisms are the ones that map $(12)$ to $(12)$, $(13)$ or $(23)$. Any automorphism fixes $\alpha$, and maps $(123)$ from the $S_3$ factor to $(123)$ or $(132)$.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen: thanks for the clue.  I confess that I still don't quite understand how one computes an enumeration of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ (or even how one does it for $\mathrm{Aut}(S_3\times C_2)$, as you do here)...  But please don't feel compelled to explain further; I have the distinct feeling that there's a *whole mass* of theorems that are relevant/useful here but that I'm not even aware of, so I probably would not understand your explanation anyway.

Comment: @kjo: Let me try to explain one way to approach this. $S_3 \times C_2$ is generated by $\alpha$, $(12)$ and $(123)$. Hence any automorphism $\phi$ is determined by its values on these elements. We already know that $\phi(\alpha) = \alpha$. Automorphisms preserve order, and there are $6$ elements of order $2$ and $2$ elements of order $3$ in the group. Hence there are $6$ possible values of $\phi((12))$ and $2$ possible values of $\phi((123))$. Therefore there are at most $6 \cdot 2 = 12$ automorphisms. What remains is to prove that an automorphism exists for each of these choices...

Comment: .. which you could do by using a presentation or the group. Or you could check that some of the choices work, and prove that those automorphisms generate a group of order $12$.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen: thanks again; before my last post, I had tried reasoning the way you describe, but my counts came out differently:  $1$ element of order $1$: $(1, 1)$; $7$ elements of order $2$: $(1, \alpha)$ plus the $6$ elements with $(12)$, $(13)$, or $(23)$ as first component; $2$ elements of order $3$: $((123), 1)$ and $((132), 1)$; and $2$ elements of order $6$: $((123), \alpha)$ and $((132), \alpha)$.  If I multiply these counts I get $1 \cdot 7 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 28$, but I'm not sure that this product counts the number of automorphisms rather than an upper bound for this number...

Comment: @kjo: Sorry, I should have said that there are $6$ noncentral elements of order $2$. We know that $\phi(\alpha) = \alpha$, so $\phi((12))$ cannot be $\alpha$ ($\phi$ must be bijective). Anyway, if you know $\phi(\alpha)$, $\phi((12))$ and $\phi((123))$, then you know $\phi(x)$ for any $x$, since any $x$ is some product of these three elements and their inverses (because $\alpha$, $(12)$ and $(123)$ generate the group). So as you see above there are $6$ possibilities for $\phi((12))$ and $2$ possibilities for $\phi((123))$, hence there are $\leq 6 \cdot 2 = 12$ automorphisms.